# Disabling href on dynamically loading html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using this piece of code to disable all links for a preview page:

```
var disableLink = function(){ return false;};
$('a').bind('click', disableLink);
```

This disables all links that get loaded staticly.
However all  tags that get loaded using ajax are still pressable.

How do I make it so that all links so even the dynamically loaded ones get disabled in my preview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use CSS - [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). According to MDN:

> The element is never the target of mouse events;

You can style the `a` tags directly:

```
a {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

However, if you don't want to disable all `a` tags on a page, you should limit it to anchor elements inside of a container:

```
#container a {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

**Demo**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#container').append('<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>');
  
    $('#child').append('<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>');
}, 1000);
```

```css
#child {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
  
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw this solution before. But This doesn't disable the <a> tags inside childeren of the #container does it?

Comment: It does - this how CSS child selector works - see Yahoo in the example.

Comment: It's odd. My <a> doesn't inside of a child x5 doesn't get the pointer-events: none; However since it is an great awnser overall I will accept this.

Comment: Is it under an iframe?

Comment: Yup. <iframe id="theme-preview-frame" src="/preview/3"></iframe>

Answer (score 3):

Please don't use **[`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** it was deprecated.

> As of jQuery 3.0, **.bind()** has been deprecated. It was superseded by the **.on()** method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, **so its use was already discouraged**.

You should use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** when you deal with new elements added dynamically to the DOM :

```
$('body').on('click','a', disableLink);
```

However the css solution posted by @OriDrori looks like the best answer for your case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation. Change the code to use the **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** event binding method:

```
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){ return false;};);
```